# on click href, how to create new html page and write html dynamic in to page using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement web application for sales. So in that i would like to generate dynamic html pages on fly by clicking on a product.

```
<a href="/products/34567.html">
    <img src="leather1.png" alt="Leather Bag" width="82" height="82">
</a>
```

when i click on leather1.png , i should redirect to 34567.html.
But 34567 html page will not be present in my source. On click image i want to create new html  page naming 34567.html and write html content in to the page using jQuery.

Can any one help me on how to approach to achieve this..

Your immediate response is highly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript cannot do that, you'll need a server sided language to write files on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for quick response..Can it be done using spring tiles concept.

Comment: @VNY, where do you expect the content of the new page to come from?

Comment: @Dan Farrell...will be pre existing in html page like templates.... i want to get response from server side and pass data in to template and generate html content..

Answer (score 1):

**i think you arelooking for this:**

check out this paper: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3776371

goodluck!

Comment: Thanks for the info.. but the link says to do dynamic changes with in the page using javascript....my expectation is something like to create a new page and push html content...

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, what you want is an AJAX call.  You'd want to have an `onclick` action on the anchors that would trigger an AJAX request, with a callback that knew how to render the result - it could replace the document object's html.  Then for useability the action should probably display a loading screen.  Finally, the action should return false so the link isn't followed.

Key point: if an onclick operation on an anchor tag returns `false`, the link is *not* followed by the browser.

I would hasten to add though, having the `href` of a link simply not work is a bit of an anti-pattern. Your HTML is telling the browser there's a related document at /products/34567.html ... SEO will not find your product 'pages'.  AJAX is all well and dandy, but this isn't the best use of it.  best if that link really worked, and the AJAX was just an optional step.  Web crawlers don't usually run JS and won't find your products - and if you want them to sell, you want google to find them!

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks, it make sense..you are pointing about the feasibility for searching products.  
But if i am not wrong, SEO will find the sales home page but not product. Once you get in to home page, then the user can choose products based on the category...So to get product information and details i would like to fire a call weather it may ajax or url request mapping and load in the newly generated html page. The html page name should be a unique product ID.
Anyways thanks..you came up with a nice point.

Comment: Yeah, SEO aside, the first paragraph explains basically what you want to do.